# Getting ClassCastException while developing UDTF in Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am getting issue ClassCastException while developing UDTF in Hive.

Here are the details :

1. I am trying to implement for loop kind of functionality where I can pass three parameters like for_each(start,stop,increment).
2. if I pass all the parameters as a values like for_each(1 , 10 , 1) it works fine.
3. whereas, for stop value parameter I am trying to pass result of one of the UDF function (eg. stopvlaue()  value like for_each(1 , stopvalue() , 1). stopo dovalue() function returns me IntWritable.
   when I try to do this I am getting below exception :
   "ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableIntObjectInspector cannot be cast to   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableConstantIntObjectInspector"

Here is my UDTF:

```
public class GenerateSeries extends GenericUDTF {
    IntWritable start;
    IntWritable end;
    IntWritable inc;
    Object[] forwardObj = null;



    @Override
    public StructObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] args) throws UDFArgumentException 
    {

        start=((WritableConstantIntObjectInspector) args[0]).getWritableConstantValue();
        end=((WritableConstantIntObjectInspector) args[1]).getWritableConstantValue();
        if (args.length == 3) 
        {
            inc =((WritableConstantIntObjectInspector) args[2]).getWritableConstantValue();
        } else {
            inc = new IntWritable(1);
        }
        this.forwardObj = new Object[1];
        ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<ObjectInspector> fieldOIs = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>();
        fieldNames.add("col0");
        fieldOIs.add(PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.getPrimitiveJavaObjectInspector(PrimitiveCategory.INT));
        return ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(fieldNames, fieldOIs);
    }
    @Override
    public void process(Object[] args) throws HiveException, UDFArgumentException 
    {
        for (int i = start.get(); i < end.get(); i = i + inc.get()) 
        {
            this.forwardObj[0] = new Integer(i);
            forward(forwardObj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws HiveException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Any Idea how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `initialize` method, in most cases, does not give you the actual value of the input to the function, as that can be different for different rows. It only tells you the types of the input. The actual values can be consistently accessed only from the `process` method. You're currently taking advantage of the one notable exception, which is for constants. The general pattern you should follow instead is:

1. Store the input inspectors in instances variables in the `initialize` method. You can check that they are types that you expect, but they won't always be `WritableConstantIntObjectInspector`. They should always be subclasses of `PrimitiveObjectInspector` and if you call the `getPrimitiveCategory` method, you should get back `PrimtiveCategory.INT`.
2. Use the stored input inspectors to retrieve the data in the objects passed in to the `process` method. For example, `Integer n = (Integer)inspector.getPrimitiveJavaObject(args[0])`